# Datatables.Server-side processing.How to get information about table?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I'm trying to follow this examles: https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side

Javascript code from example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

HTML code:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

And this is server-side script:

```
<?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'datatables_demo';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'start_date',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'salary',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '$'.number_format($d);
        }
    )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

How the server receives the information about the table?Current page number, number of records displayed and so on?
And how can i pass this information to ASP.NET MVC controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found at [there](http://justinmichaels.net/using-jquery-datatables-with-asp-net-mvc-for-serverside-filtering-sorting-and-paging)

Using jQuery DataTables with ASP.NET Mvc for server-side filtering, sorting and paging

Answer (score 1):

With every Ajax request jQuery DataTables sends parameters described in [Sent Parameters](https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) section.

For example, `start` and `length` parameters indicate first record number and number of records requested, see below:

> `start`
>   Paging first record indicator. This is the start point in the current data set (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record).
>
> `length`
>   Number of records that the table can display in the current draw. It is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to this number, unless the server has fewer records to return. Note that this can be -1 to indicate that all records should be returned (although that negates any benefits of server-side processing!)